# Show Child Div Above Elements on Parent Div Level using z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to show a child div (That is within a parent container) above a div on the same level of the parent div. I can use jQuery, and CSS to manipulate the z-index. In the example below, I want the Calendar to be position above the gridRight, however with a z-index of 1000 and the gridRight at 2, it still does not show above it. The user is able to drag the Calendar around. How can I do this so Calendar shows above gridRight?

-The elements have the property position: absolute

Here is the basic JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LTRyd/1/

- I want to be able to move the red square above the green square, all while the black square will still show below the green square.

  ```
  <div id="mainContainer" class="mainContainer">
       <div id="grid1" class="grid"> <!--Has to have Z-Index of 1-->
            <div id="Calendar" class="item"></div> <!--Z-Index of 1000-->
  </div>            
  </div>
  <div id="gridLeft" class="gridLeft"></div> <!--Has to have Z-Index of 2-->
  <div id="gridRight" class="gridRight"></div> <!--Has to have Z-Index of 2-->
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Z-Index only takes effect on positioned elements.

You will have to alter your CSS to position the elements you want z-indexed:

```
#Calendar
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
}

#grid2
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

**edit:**

"Within a stacking context, child elements are stacked according to the same rules previously explained. Importantly, the z-index values of its child stacking contexts only have meaning in this parent. Stacking contexts are treated atomically as a single unit in the parent stacking context."

[The stacking context - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context)

Essentially, stacking is resolved within the parent element. All stacking occurs within the parent, and then that parent's stacking order is in the context of its other siblings, regardless of the stacking order of the children within it.

So while `Calendar` will have a z-index of 1000, that z-index will only apply against the stacking of other children of `grid1`

Comment: The elements have position: absolute already, so I dont think that can be the problem.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps you could post a jsFiddle with your code so we could take a better look at the situation?

Comment: Check my edit and the article linked in it. The Calendar's stacking context is different than that of the gridRight.

Comment: So, Would I essentially have to take my Calendar div and append it so it is on the same level as gridLeft and gridRight? Is there no other way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not seeing any other way after skimming through that documentation. As long as Calendar's parent is below gridRight, then Calendar will also always be below gridRight.